# how to use RDLC in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, reporting

Hi  I've created a new solution on .net 6  on VS2022 , and now I need to create reports but it looks like there is no way in vs2022. is there a way to use reporting services RDLC files in WPF on VS2002 ?

Mean a while I've open the solution on VS2009 in order to use it for building RDLC reports, but when I try to associate the data source to an Object  I got this error
[image]

My object is a Class in a referenced project (class library .net6) the class  is:

```
   public  class prueba
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
        public int prop2 { get; set; }
        public int prop3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please @KillemAll if you find any solution to this, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I have added Visual Studio DataSet object rather than using my reference project dataset.

[image]

Configure the dataset exactly as my custom dataset.

[image]

Now, this dataset is available to work in RDLC report, rest of the work has been done in my code behind to fill the VSDataSet.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [RDLC Report Designer Add-In for Visual Studio 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022).

To *use* those reports in your application, you need an RDLC renderer (aka "Microsoft ReportViewer"), which is available for .NET 4.0-4.8 as a nuget package:

- [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/)
- [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms/)

Do note, though, that **Microsoft did not release a ReportViewer for .NET Core or .NET 5+**, and they have announced that do not intend to release one in the future (see, for example, [the comments on this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-6/)).

There are some enthusiast ports/recompilations floating around on github and nuget, but they are not from Microsoft, nor has Microsoft given them permission to do that, so using those packages carries a certain amount of technical and legal risk. That's not something you want to do in a commercial project.

Answer (score 1):

You only can use projects with netstandard, 2.0 or 2.1

so the class you will use as a data source only can be in a project using .NetFramework or netstandard.